# Update sql record in c# wpf

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

I have a User class that gets and sets data about users.

```
private string userId;  
        public string UserId
        {
            get { return userId; }
            set {
                userId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("UserId"));
            }
        }

        private string employeeNumber;
        public string EmployeeNumber
        {
            get { return employeeNumber; }
            set {
                employeeNumber = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("EmployeeNumber"));
            }
        }
         ...
```

The data is retrieved from a select all query into an observablecollection and then displayed in a simple wpf window that has a combobox to list all users by userid and textboxes that displays the rest of the user data.  All this works great.  However, the edit/save has me over a barrel.

After a text box is edited and the save button is clicked the following method is executed

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        User user = (User)grdUserManagement.DataContext;
        try
        {
            UserDB.UpdateUser(user);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Obviously, the user passed to the Update statement is the new edited user.

```
 public static void UpdateUser(User user)
    {
        SqlConnection connection = BusinessDB.GetConnection();
        string updateStatement =
            "UPDATE Employees SET userid = '" + user.UserId.ToString() + "', " +
            "password = '" + user.Password.ToString() + "', " +
            "empno = '" + user.EmployeeNumber.ToString() + "', " +
            "firstname = '" + user.FirstName.ToString() + "', " +
            "lastname = '" + user.LastName.ToString() + "' " +
            "WHERE (userid = '" + user.UserId + "' " +
            "OR userid IS NULL AND '" +user.UserId.ToString() + "' IS NULL) " +
            "AND (password = '" + user.Password.ToString() + "' " +
            "OR password IS NULL AND '" + user.Password.ToString() + "' IS NULL) " +
            "AND empno = '" + user.EmployeeNumber.ToString() + "' " +
            "AND firstname = '" + user.FirstName.ToString() + "' " +
            "AND lastname = '" + user.LastName.ToString() + "'";

             SqlCommand updateCommand = new SqlCommand(updateStatement, connection);

              try
        {
            connection.Open();
            updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

    }
```

...nothing is saved because there is nothing in the table that matches the new 'edited' data.

How do I write this to check for concurrency and update the record?

Comment: Regarding the above issue, what is the best method to ensure concurrency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `update` a table data using the `PrimaryKey` in `where clause` itself and never try to `update` the `PrimaryKey` in DB.. Please use the `Parameters` to prevent from `SQLInjections`.

[**Use of Paramters to prevent SQLInjection**](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/)

**Using Block:**
`using` statement allows the programmer to specify when `objects` that use resources should release them. The `object` provided to the using statement must implement the `IDisposable` interface. This interface provides the Dispose method, which should *release the object's resources.*

```
using (SqlConnection conn =
            new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd =
                new SqlCommand("UPDATE Employees SET firstname=@firstname, lastname=@lastname" +
                    " WHERE Id=@Id", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id",user.UserId );
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname",user.FirstName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname",user.LastName);
                //add whatever parameters you required to update here
                int rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
    }
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks to both Shekhar Shete and Pushpraj Ruhal both answers were very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You may not practically update the key field while keeping it in the where clause at the same time. Secondly where clause looks so complicated for a simple update.

So the solution is to have a dedicated primary key, hidden from the view and use the same in the where clause to update the rest of the fields, do not use all of the fields in where clause. A GUID kind of filed works best here, provides uniqueness. A simple running number can also work for you.

See sample below, I am referring ID as a primary key in your table
eg.

```
string updateStatement =
        "UPDATE Employees SET userid = '" + user.UserId + "', " +
        "password = '" + user.Password + "', " +
        "empno = '" + user.EmployeeNumber + "', " +
        "firstname = '" + user.FirstName + "', " +
        "lastname = '" + user.LastName + "' " +
        "WHERE ID = '" + user.ID + "'"
```

Comment: +1, however it might be mentioned that the query should use parameters to avoid SQL injection.